# UDP Client - Exception in creating socketOnly one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming

I am creating a UDP client in my c# application.

```
labelEP = new System.Net.IPEndPoint(tempAdd, ethPortAddress);
recvMIUCmndsSocket = new UdpClient(labelEP);
Socket temp = recvMIUCmndsSocket.Client;
 //Allow broadcasts
temp.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.Broadcast, 1);
```

Whenever i start my application it works fine. If there is any problem in my application, the application restarts on its own. Some times when an application restarts I am facing the exception :

`"Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted "`

It seems to be the garbage collector didn't free the previous instance of udpclient socket. Could that happen?

Regards
Raju

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collector would take care of disposing managed objects. As per my basic understanding, sockets are native windows objects and .net has provided managed wrappers around them. Also once my architect had told me that when we close a port or a socket, windows takes some time to close it. I think you are facing this issue because of that behavior of windows sockets.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely familiar with C#, but I have been doing some similar work in Java recently, and I discovered three things.

First, you need to close connections, even after error conditions. It can get a little messy, since (in Java, at least), some calls to clean up after yourself can generate exceptions.

Second, this explicit closing of connections lets the garbage collector do its job better. However, you don't really control when the GC runs, so you can't anticipate that the connection will be cleaned up and the socket ready for use again immediately. If you immediately try to reopen a connection, the socket might not be quite ready yet.

Third, the operating system is often involved in managing network connections and network resources. So just because you and your environment have released and cleaned up the resource doesn't mean the OS has (re)made it available yet.